# How to send files from Angular 2 to API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have below code in my page and trying to upload files from WEB API. I have tried by passing the files data in formData to WEB API but I am not aware how read files which are sent in formData.

How can I send files from angular to WEB API and how can I read them in API?

**Angular2 frontend part**

```html
<input #fileInput type="file"/>
<button (click)="addFile()">Add</button>
```

**Angular2 Component**

```js
@ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput;

addFile(): void {
    let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {
        let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];
        this.uploadService
            .upload(fileToUpload)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    }
}
```

**Angular2 Upload Service**

```js
upload(fileToUpload: any) {
 
// var input =?? ; How can I send files to WEBAPI controller action.
    return this.http
        .post("/api/uploadFile", input);
}
```

**WEB API**

```
[HttpPost]
    public string uploadFile()
    {
   // How can I handle files which are sent from UI
        return "uploaded";
    }
```

Comment: What kind of files are you submitting? Text/images/everything ?

Comment: I am not restricting user for a specific file

Answer (score 0):

On frontend, we send file:

```
this.uploadService
    .upload(theFile)
    .subscribe(
        res => console.log('Uploaded file with content:', res),
        err => console.error('Failed with error:', error)
    );
```

In the service:

```
upload(fileToUpload) {
    return this.http.post('api/file/endpoint',
        fileToUpload,
        new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    )
    .map(res => res.text()); //mapping to text just to see the string response propagated to component subscribe
}
```

ASP.NET Controller

```
[Route("api/file/endpoint")]
[HttpPost]
public string GetFile()
{
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        return stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

You can, of course, use other ways to handle the stream, including async ones.

Comment: I have got the solution. i.e we shouldn't send any headers so that it works.